# detach laravel paginate object and list items to separate veriables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**hello, is that possible to detach Laravel pagination object (without items) to a another variable and its items to another variable?**
eg:

I'm currently working on product list that project that using without pagination (just ->get() ) so I need to inject paginated items to  that variable and send pagination Object data in separate variable.. hope you guys can understand.

the current way is:

```
 $products = Products::get();
```

I just need send pagination items to that variable and pagination object in another variable.
just like this:

```
$products_paginate = Products::paginate(10);
$paginateObj = $products_paginate ->pagination();
$products = $products_paginate ->items();
```

items should not in pagination data object.

Comment: yes, what is wrong with what you are doing now? You have access to all the public methods here https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html

Comment: thank you.. `pagination()`  is not exist function i think.   `items()` getting as array.  is there way to remove items from pagination after its stored in other veriable?

Comment: probably not without being hacky, can you just make a variable containing a new array of just the items you want, pull in exactly what you need? or maybe try "toArray" and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how you can get links from collection:

```
$paginateObj = $products_paginate->linkCollection();
```